# update multi records and insert if not present

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Lets say my test data is

```
db.multiArr.insert({"ID" : "fruit1","Keys" : "apple"})
db.multiArr.insert({"ID" : "fruit2","Keys" : "carrot"})
db.multiArr.find({'ID': {$in: ['fruit1', 'fruit2']}})
```

if i want to update or insert a ID i can do it using

```
db.multiArr.update(
    {'ID': "fruit12"},
    {
        'ID': "fruit12"
        "$push": {
            "Keys": "tomato"
        }
    },
    upsert=True
)
```

i want to update or insert multiple records, i know the below query inserts only 1 row

```
db.multiArr.update(
     {"ID": {"$in: ["fruit123", "fruit1234"]}},
     {"ID": "---", "Keys": "tomato"},
     upsert=true
)
```

is there a way to update/insert multiple records?
[image]

Comment: Are you asking if you start with this array `["fruit123", "fruit1234"]` then how to insert/upsert multiple documents with `"tomato"` always as the value to `"Keys"`? You realize that you basically kludged this with `"ID": "---"` in order to avoid the error with `$in` and upsert in the first place don't you? I'm not sure I see the "practical" utility.

Comment: the thing is i want to update the existing records in the collection if id exists or else insert the record with the new id, instead of looping for each id

Comment: So your intention is to "create" with the supplied `"ID"` value from the array. Yes? Just noting since `"ID": "---"` and the whole update document is specified in a way which will overwrite the supplied value. We understand the upsert part, it's just the rest of your intended action that is not clear.

Comment: i have updated the question with the requirement. you can see the image in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking on this is the wrong way around. Instead you take the "array" and turn that into operations. Instead of sending multiple "requests" you send multiple "operations" in "one request". With Bulk Operations using [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

```js
var newKeys = ["fruit123", "fruit1234" ];

db.multiArr.bulkWrite(
  newkeys.map( key => {
    return {
      "updateOne": {
        "filter": { "ID": key },
        "update": { "$set": { "Keys": "tomato" } },
        "upsert": true
      }
    }
  })   
)
```

Here using a regular JavaScript [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) to transform the array content of `newKeys` into an array of "bulk write operations" statements to send to the server. In other languages the basic concept remains the same.

Over the wire, the send and response with the server is done in "one request", whilst the "package" sent for execution contains multiple actions.

If needed the return of this method in all API's is a [`BulkWriteResult`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/BulkWriteResult/) which contains details of matched documents, updates and upserts as appropriate.